# Insert a row and select or insert foreign key via a subquery

Tags: mysql

For the last two days I am stuck with the following problem *I want to insert data in the logintime table with one query.* I am running MySQL 5.7.21

The problem I face however: there is a possibility that the player doesn't exists in the player table, so therefor I am looking for a solution that looks up the foreign key and if it doesn't exists create a new player in the player table and use the newly created player id in the logintime table.

Player table:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | type |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | Steve |    2 |
|  2 | Tim   |    1 |
+----+-------+------+
```

Logintime table:

```
+---------------------+------------+----------+
|      logintime      | logouttime | playerid |
+---------------------+------------+----------+
| 2018-02-04 12:44:11 | NULL       |        1 |
| 2018-02-03 10:55:32 | NULL       |        2 |
| 2018-02-03 09:22:02 | NULL       |        1 |
+---------------------+------------+----------+
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insertOnline (IN Name VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
DECLARE playerid INT;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO players (name) VALUES (Name);
    SET playerid = (SELECT id FROM players p WHERE p.name = Name);
    INSERT INTO playersonline (playerid) VALUES (playerid);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working the way I want it to using a stored procedure. If someone has a better suggestion I'd love to hear it!